$\lfloor x \phi \rfloor - \lfloor (x-1) \phi \rfloor = 1$ iff $x = \lfloor (n-1) \phi \rfloor + n$ where $\phi$ is the golden ratio
I want to prove (or disprove) that for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$, $\lfloor x \phi \rfloor - \lfloor (x-1) \phi \rfloor = 1$ iff $x = \lfloor (n-1) \phi \rfloor + n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
I've first tried to prove that $x = \lfloor (n-1) \phi \rfloor + n$ implies that $\lfloor x \phi \rfloor - \lfloor (x-1) \phi \rfloor = 1$, but nothing is working. Let $k = \lfloor (n-1) \phi \rfloor$, so that $x = n + k$. So far, I've gotten:
\begin{align}
\lfloor x \phi \rfloor - \lfloor (x-1) \phi \rfloor =
\lfloor (n+k) \phi \rfloor - \lfloor (n+k-1) \phi \rfloor = \lfloor (n+k) \cdot \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \rfloor - \lfloor (n+k-1) \cdot \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \rfloor \\
\end{align}
There are 2 cases.
Case 1: $n+k-1$ is even (I don't know how to reduce this expression otherwise).
Then, we get
\begin{align*}
\lfloor \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} + \frac{(n+k-1) (1 + \sqrt{5})}2 \rfloor - \lfloor \frac{(n+k-1) (1 + \sqrt{5})}2 \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} + \frac{(n+k-1) \sqrt{5}}2 \rfloor - \lfloor \frac{(n+k-1) \sqrt{5}}2 \rfloor
\end{align*}
Since $\frac{n+k-1}2$ is an integer. I don't know how to proceed from here though.
(Note that this question comes from Wythoff's game.)

May be related? Explicit form for a difficult sequence and A001468.

@peterwhy yes, I basically want a proof for why it works.
